# VBA - Solver not changing

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, solver, vba

I am trying to set a VBA loop with "for" in a Solver code, as shown below:

The problem is when I try to put a String in the condition:

```
    SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_11, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_11, Relation:=3, **FormulaText:=address_12**
```

The address should be "AX155" as it reads the column letter "AX" and concatenates with the line "155".
When I end the running the SolverBox, it indicates the following:[image]

The first two conditions should be: $AV$155 <= $AW$155 and $AU$155 <= $AX$155 
and it reads completely wrong.

The image below is the Spreadsheet with the data the references are picking up [image]

Code:

```
Sub interpolacao()

Dim myarray As Variant
Dim myarray_2 As String

Dim column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6 As String
Dim address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4, address_5, address_6, address_7, address_8, _
    address_9, address_10, address_11, address_12 As Variant
Dim address_13, address_14, address_15, address_16, address_17, address_18, address_19, _
    address_20, address_21, address_22, address_23, address_24 As String


    For x = 3 To 3

    myarray_2 = myarray(x)


                    column_1 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 47).Text
                    address_1 = "" & column_1 & myarray_2 & ""

                    column_2 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 46).Text
                    address_2 = "" & column_2 & myarray_2 - 3 & ":" & column_2 & myarray_2 & ""

                    column_3 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 44).Text
                    address_3 = "" & column_3 & myarray_2 & ""
                    address_4 = "" & column_3 & myarray_2 - 1 & ""
                    address_5 = "" & column_3 & myarray_2 - 2 & ""
                    address_6 = "" & column_3 & myarray_2 - 3 & ""

                    address_7 = "" & column_2 & myarray_2 & ""
                    address_8 = "" & column_2 & myarray_2 - 1 & ""
                    address_9 = "" & column_2 & myarray_2 - 2 & ""
                    address_10 = "" & column_2 & myarray_2 - 3 & ""

                    column_4 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 47).Text
                    column_5 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 50).Text
                    address_11 = "" & column_4 & myarray_2 & ""
                    address_12 = "" & column_5 & myarray_2 & ""

                    column_6 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 48).Text
                    column_7 = Worksheets("PRICES_ASIA_PET_FOB_WEEKLY").Cells(134, 49).Text
                    address_13 = "" & column_6 & myarray_2 & ""
                    address_14 = "" & column_7 & myarray_2 & ""

            SolverReset
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_3, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_3, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_4, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_4, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_5, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_5, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_6, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_6, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_7, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_7, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-0.01"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_8, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_8, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-0.01"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_9, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_9, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-0.01"
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_10, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_10, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-0.01"

            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_11, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_11, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=address_12
            SolverOk SetCell:=address_1, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=address_2, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
                    'SolverDelete CellRef:=address_13, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                    SolverAdd CellRef:=address_13, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="""" & address_14 & """"

            SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
            SolverFinish 'KeepFinal:=1
```

Could you help me out?

Comment: Comment on your code: you only need one call of `SolverOK`. You can then call `SolverAdd` multiple times to set up constraints.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger to verify the values of your variables?

Comment: @xidgel Thank you very much! it solved!